# White mold on pot of avocado tree

Tags: containers, avocado, repotting

Soon after I moved my avocado tree to a terracotta pot (from IKEA), something like white mold appeared on the outside of the pot and it hasn't gone away for months.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Here are photos of the pot and the tree:

[image: plant]
[image: plant]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nothing to worry about, though you may not like the way it looks. Terracotta pots allow moisture to permeate their clay, and minerals from the soil and water end up depositing on the outside of the pot, usually looking white, like yours. You can try scrubbing it off with a brush and cloth if you don't like it, and then switch to watering with distilled water or rain water to avoid further deposits, see here https://www.edibleblooms.com.au/blog/why-are-my-terra-cotta-pots-turning-white/